# How can I change a series of dates into one date R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a data frame of polls, one column of which is titled `Date.s.administered`, and is formatted as a string containing the dates for which the poll was administered. For example, `"January 16-20, 2019"`, or `"December 1-11, 2018"`. The entire column looks like this:

```
[1] "November 3–5, 2018"    "November 1–2, 2018"   
[3] "October 28–30, 2018"   "October 22–28, 2018"  
[5] "October 15–28, 2018"   "October 15–28, 2018"  
[7] "October 25–26, 2018"   "October 18–21, 2018"  
[9] "October 15–21, 2018"   "October 12–18, 2018"  
[11] "October 10–14, 2018"   "October 9–13, 2018"   
[13] "October 9–13, 2018"    "October 8–13, 2018"   
[15] "October 8–11, 2018"    "October 3–9, 2018"
```

How would I manipulate this column so that it displays only the last date of the series (for example, `"March 1-4, 2018"` becomes `"March 4, 2018"`)?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to make an easy to use example of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
gsub("\\d+–", "", df$Date.s.administered)
```

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date.s.administered = c("November 3–5, 2018", "November 1–2, 2018"))
```

Output:

```
[1] "November 5, 2018" "November 2, 2018"
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the unicode "dash" my regex works differently depending on if I type "3-5" vs copying yours. How did you get that character?

Comment: Yeah tbh I don't know which type of dash it is, I copy pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `lubridate` package in combination with regex to extract a string pattern then convert to a standard date field.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))

x <- "March 1-4, 2018"

mdy(gsub("(^.+)(\\s\\d-)(\\d)(,\\s)(\\d{4}$)", '\\1 \\3 \\5', x))
#> [1] "2018-03-04"
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `tidyverse` could be:

```
date %>%
 separate(date, c("date1", "date2"), sep = "–") %>%
 mutate(date = paste(sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", date1), date2, sep = " ")) %>%
 select(date)

              date
1 November 2, 2018
2 October 28, 2018
3 October 28, 2018
```

First, it is separating the "date" column into "date1" and date2" based on "–". Then, it is keeping only letters from "date1" and combining it with "date2" into the desired "date" column.

Sample data:

```
date <- data.frame(date = c("November 1–2, 2018",
          "October 22–28, 2018",
          "October 15–28, 2018"))
```